# How to Efficiently Combine Sparse Matrices Vertically

Tags: matlab, indexing, block, sparse-matrix

My goal is to combine many sparse matrices together to form one large sparse matrix. The only two ideas I've been able to think of are (1) create a large sparse matrix and overwrite certain blocks, (2) create the blocks individually use `vertcat` to form my final sparse matrix. However,I've read that [overwriting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html#br7572b) sparse matrices is quite inefficient, and I've also read that vertcat isn't exactly computationally efficient. (I didn't both to consider using a for loop because of how inefficient they are).

What other alternatives do I have then?

**Edit**: By combine I mean "gluing" matrices together (vertically), the elements don't interact.

Comment: What happens if you just add them together? More specifically - what are the dimensions of your matrices, and what does a "combined" matrix look like in your books? Can you give a toy example?

Comment: @Floris dimensions can range from 2x2 to 2^18 x 2^18 or whatever the maximum that Matlab can handle for my script. I think an error generates somewhere around 2^18. A toy example would be anything arbitrary. The only thing that's fixed in my matrix is the first and last block, which are `speye`, but everything in between varies (though their sizes are fixed)

Comment: @Floris also I couldn't add them b/c I couldn't figure out a global index that would work for all the matrices. I just saw your post though, so I don't think that will be problem.

Comment: I guess my question is "how do you intend to combine". When you combine a 10x10 and a 10x10 is the result 10x10 or 20x10?

Comment: @Floris ah I see. Sorry, 10x10 with, say a 5x10, would be 15x10. The elements don't interact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the matlab help, you can "disassemble" a sparse matrix with

```
[i,j,s] = find(S);
```

This means that if you have two matrices `S` and `T`, and you want to (effectively) `vertcat` them, you can do

```
[is, js, ss] = find(S);
[it, jt, st] = find(T);
ST = sparse([is; it + size(S,1)], [js; jt], [ss; st]);
```

Not sure if this is very efficient... but I'm guessing it's not too bad.

EDIT: using a 2000x1000 sparse matrix with a density of 1%, and combining it with another that has density of 2%, the above code ran in 0.016 seconds on my machine. Just doing `[S;T]` was 10x faster. What makes you think vertical concatenation is slow?

EDIT2: assuming you need to do this with "many" sparse matrices, the following works (this assumes you want them all "in the same place"):

```
m = 1000; n = 2000; density = 0.01;
N = 100;
Q = cell(1, N);
is = Q;
js = Q;
ss = Q;
numrows = 0; % keep track of dimensions so far

for ii = 1:N
    Q{ii} = sprandn(m+ii, n-jj, density); % so each matrix has different size
    [a b c] = find(Q{ii});
    sz = size(Q{ii}); 
    is{ii} = a' + numrows; js{ii}=b'; ss{ii}=c'; % append "on the corner"
    numrows = numrows + sz(1); % keep track of the size
end

tic
ST = sparse([is{:}], [js{:}], [ss{:}]);
fprintf(1, 'using find takes %.2f sec\n', toc);
```

Output:

```
using find takes 0.63 sec
```

The big advantage of this method is that you don't need to have the same number of columns in your individual sparse arrays... it will all get sorted out by the `sparse` command which will simply consider the missing columns to be all zeros.

Comment: So are you still suggesting to use vertcat or find?

Comment: The `find` method (and the implicit `horzcat` I am doing with `[is{:}]` ) seems to be quite efficient. You might ask yourself how you generated the original (source) sparse matrices; if you had them in the `(i,j,s)` format to begin with, you might never need the intermediate `find` step...

Comment: In the first line of the for loop, do you mean `n-ii`? `jj` isn't defined?

Comment: Yes of course - typo. Just wanted to make matrices of different sizes, to prove that I could... I could not copy/paste from the computer on which I was running matlab (long story) so had to type it out. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the answer already given.

I have changed the experiment a bit, to be able to join matricies vertically (it should have the same width), so you we do no need to tweak `n` by extracting `ii` (which is mistyped by `jj`).

This approach

```
tic
ST = sparse([is{:}], [js{:}], [ss{:}]);
fprintf(1, 'using find takes %.2f sec\n', toc);
```

with its `0.45 sec` is much slower than this one

```
tic
ST = vertcat(Q{:});
fprintf(1, 'using vertcat takes %.2f sec\n', toc);
```

with `0.18 sec` average.

I also checked it with profiler, first example is expectedly slower, since at least the memory allocation is 100 times higher. Most probably, because of `[ss{:}]` array constructions which explicityly copies the data to the new array.

However, even with precomputed vectors the speed is `0,3 sec` vs `0,18 sec` for `vertcat`.

Thus, I suggest that `vertcat` is a better option for original problem. At least in 2021 :)